# Apache Spark 3.0 Different Operating Systems Network Drive

Tags: macos, apache-spark, ubuntu, cluster-computing

I have an `Apache Spark 3.0` set up on a multi-node cluster through SSH.
I'm using a network drive which I have all nodes connected to however the file directory is different on `Mac OSX` than the `Ubuntu` which fails.
For example, the `MAC OsX` accesses the network drive by `/Volumes/<Drive>`
The `Ubuntu` access the network drive by `/run/user/1000/gvfs/<Drive>`
The problem with this is that if use the Mac as the host and tell it to read the `network driver`, the other machines won't be able to access it even though they're all connected to it so it errors out with failures on the Ubuntu nodes. Is there a way I can have the same address so all the machines can intepret it in `pyspark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create symlinks to the same location on all machines and use that symlink instead of the actual location.  something like this:

```sh
mkdir /some/location
OS_NAME=$(uname -s)
if [ "$OS_NAME" = "Darwin" ]; then
   ln -s /Volumes/<Drive> /some/location/drive
elif [ "$OS_NAME" = "Linux" ]; then
   ln -s /run/user/1000/gvfs/<Drive> /some/location/drive
else
   echo "Unsupported OS"
fi
```